# What is the time unit which is in PhpMyadmin Server status page?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In PHPMyAdmin `server_status.php` page, I have seen **time** column having some integer values. What is the **uni**t of the time column?

[image: See this screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

output of `server_status.php` is a pretty table with the data from `show processlist;` query. as you can see in [their reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html):

> The time in seconds that the thread has been in its current state. For
>   a slave SQL thread, the value is the number of seconds between the
>   timestamp of the last replicated event and the real time of the slave
>   machine.

so, it's seconds.